# Input field to change img attributes for multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

**Issue:** Cannot change attributes src and alt independently for multiple images. Any change made, affects all the other images that have previously had a change made.

**Question:** How can I optimize following JS/Jquery to allow attribute changes for multiple images?

See full code here: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vepbvn2/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#editImage").hide();
    $("img").click(function () {
        var imgChange = this;
        $('#imageAlt').val($(imgChange).attr('alt'));
         $('#imageSrc').val($(imgChange).attr('src'));
        $("#editImage").css({
            top: $(this).offset().top - $('#editImage').height() - 5,
            left: $(this).offset().left
        }).show();
        $("#imageEditDone").click(function () {
            var imgSrc = $("#imageSrc").val();
            var imgAlt = $("#imageAlt").val();
            $(imgChange).attr('src', imgSrc).attr('alt', imgAlt);
        });           
    });
});
$("#imageEditDone").click(function () {
    $("#editImage").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding a click handler within another click handler repeatedly which is a no-no. Also, you need to change the scope of your imgChange variable. Try:

```
var imgChange;
$(function () {
    $("#editImage").hide();
    $("img").click(function () {
        imgChange = this;
        $('#imageAlt').val($(imgChange).attr('alt'));
        $('#imageSrc').val($(imgChange).attr('src'));
        $("#editImage").css({
            top: $(this).offset().top - $('#editImage').height() - 5,
            left: $(this).offset().left
        }).show();
        $("#imageSrc").text(imgChange.attr('alt', this));
    });
});
$("#imageEditDone").click(function () {
    $("#editImage").hide();
    var imgSrc = $("#imageSrc").val();
    var imgAlt = $("#imageAlt").val();
    $(imgChange).attr('src', imgSrc).attr('alt', imgAlt);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1vepbvn2/2/)**

I'm just not sure what you're trying to do with the line `$("#imageSrc").text(imgChange.attr('alt', this));`, although it doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: Ah that was a scrap line I should have been removed. Thanks for your help. Upvoted and will mark as correct answer in two min.